# Wordpress tries to load "next page" after done loading current page

Tags: performance

I have a fresh 3.5.1 installation - default theme, no plugins.

Running HTTPFox on Firefox shows that after a GET-request of any given page in Wordpress has finished loading, a GET-request is sent for the `rel='next'` page:

```
<link rel='next' title='Next Page Title' href='http://www.domain.com/next-page/' />
```

and fails:

```
00:10:04.992    0.556   698 245 GET (Aborted)   text/html (NS_BINDING_ABORTED)  http://www.domain.com/next-page/
```

My question - is this on purpose? Is wordpress doing some kind of preloading?  I'd like to understand why it is doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn’t WordPress, it is Firefox’ [Link prefetching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Link_prefetching_FAQ). You can [turn it off](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/firefox/quick-tip-turn-off-prefetching-in-firefox/).

Serve those requests nothing:

```
# Serve Firefox' prefetch requests an empty page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_X_MOZ} ^prefetch$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=204]
```

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you! For anyone wanting to prevent prefetching for your wordpress site, the following code removes the `rel="next"` link:  `remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head');`

Comment: Actually, the edit from toscho is a better solution.